# CSS not properly load after going http to https in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, ssl

After using `SSL` certificate, there is problem in frontend.

1. Problem in font family css, it is load but not work same as work before on http.

How to resolve that problem, i have done all setting in backend like this

```
Use Secure URLs in Frontend : Yes

Use Secure URLs in Admin : Yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the `console (F12)` for errors, if you load page through `HTTPS protocol`, you also have to load all scripts, fonts, images through `HTTPS`. Also note an icon next to browser Url field, it is strike through if everything is not loaded through `HTTPS protocol`.

Comment: yes...after click f12..it is giving an error==> Blocked loading mixed active content " http:// fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Abel"

Comment: how to change this http to https ?

Comment: When you load font, load it using https://  - so, if possible use relative links.  Not whole path, but '/ + path'

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27451124/https-mixed-content-errors